# Deploying Ruby on Rails app that require node.js as well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nvm

I am trying to install a ruby on rails app on AWS via elastic beanstalk (end goal is zero downtime deployment) but the problem i am getting errors while running the "AppDeployPreHook/11_asset_compilation.sh" step

I have selected ruby platform with passenger and at AppDeployPreHook/11_asset_compilation.sh step when it reaches following step

```
> @ build:client /var/app/ondeck/client
> npm run ensure-node-version && webpack --config webpack.client.config.js
```

I get following error code

```
  npm ERR! Linux 4.14.88-72.76.amzn1.x86_64
  npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/bin/npm" "run" "ensure-node-version"
  npm ERR! node v4.6.0
  npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
  npm ERR! file sh
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno ENOENT
  npm ERR! syscall spawn
  npm ERR! @ ensure-node-version: `check-node-version --package`
  npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the @ ensure-node-version script 'check-node-version --package'.
  npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the  package,
  npm ERR! not with npm itself.
  npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
  npm ERR!     check-node-version --package
  npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
  npm ERR!     npm bugs
  npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR!     npm owner ls
  npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

  npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
  npm ERR!     /var/app/ondeck/client/npm-debug.log

  npm ERR! Linux 4.14.88-72.76.amzn1.x86_64
  npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build:client"
  npm ERR! node v4.6.0
  npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! @ build:client: `npm run ensure-node-version && webpack --config webpack.client.config.js`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the @ build:client script 'npm run ensure-node-version && webpack --config webpack.client.config.js'.
  npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the  package,
  npm ERR! not with npm itself.
  npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
  npm ERR!     npm run ensure-node-version && webpack --config webpack.client.config.js
  npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
  npm ERR!     npm bugs
  npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR!     npm owner ls
  npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have tried to install and set the npm just before the execution of this script

```
  v7.8.0 is already installed.
  Now using node v7.8.0 (npm v4.2.0)
  Now using node v7.8.0 (npm v4.2.0)
```

but for some unknown reason, the version of node and npm gets reset in the very next task

I have tried all possible solutions that i could think of my so far i haven't managed to solve it.

Any help in this regard would be really helpful

Comment: One of the problem is that elastic beanstalk is using default node and npm version

`[ec2-user@ip-172-31-35-134 ~]$ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/bin/node --version
v4.6.0

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-35-134 ~]$ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/bin/npm --version
2.15.9`

Comment: Where is the documentation for `AppDeployPreHook/11_asset_compilation.sh`?  What happens if you ssh into your EC2 instance and run `npm run ensure-node-version && webpack --config webpack.client.config.js`?

Comment: Can you downgrade your `node` version? Or `npm`? Or `ensure-node-version`? Until it works.

Comment: problem is node and npm version is managed by elastic beanstalk; as in /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/........


I need a way to upgrade that to version 7.8.0

Comment: If you are using shell scripts, can't you just use `yum update node` to update the system installed version before building? Can't you use the full path to `node` so it doesn't use a different one on the `$PATH`?

Comment: I am not using any custom script; also the node version is provided by aws; any manual over write will be lost when the next time elastic beanstalk launches new node